# How to send HTTP Request in node js under proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, typescript, visual-studio-code

Following node js code works well and get all the required results.

But when i run the code in the computer under proxy settings defined. It doesnt give the result.

```
    var options: https.RequestOptions = {
                        host: item.hostname,
                        port: +item.port,
                        path: item.path,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: newHeader

                    }

var req = https.request(options, function(res){
                        if(res.statusCode !== 200){
                            //reject();
                            //return;
                        }

                        var result = '';
                        res.setEncoding('utf8');
                        res.on('data', function(chunk){
                            result += chunk;
                        });
                        res.on('end', function(){
                            resolve(result);
                        });

                        res.on('error', function(e){
                            reject(e);
                        });
                    });
```

**How to enable proxy support in http module** requests in NODE JS that it checks **if there is any proxy defined** and perform that enabled request.

```
options data in debug mode :

headers:Object
Accept:"application/json;api-version=3.0-preview.1"
Content-Length:104
Content-Type:"application/json"
host:"marketplace.visualstudio.com"
method:"POST"
path:"/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery"
port:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy should be the `host`/`port` and the `path` is the final path of the request that the proxy should make (`host:port/path`).

Basically e.g. if making a request through a proxy on localhost:8888:

```
path = host + path, host = 'localhost', port = 8888;
```

Comment: how to get the computer default proxy and port from http module ?

Comment: You can't get it from `http` module. Also it is OS specific and I cannot find a module that does that with a quick search.

Comment: so only way is to allow user to set the proxy settings in the application in order to work under proxy ?